# Salesforce Community inline.js file

Tags: community

We are working on page load performance in our community.   We have noticed the "inline.js" file is the slowest to load (500-700ms) and the file is totally empty.   Does anyone know what this file is for or how to suppress it.   Thanks

Comment: Are you using any standard template for community?

Comment: Using Napili...  but in this specific case its a visual force page that wraps lightning components.   When inspecting the standard pages inline.js has content and comes down fast(er).